# MVC + Pass unselected values in listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have 2 simple selectbox controls (@Html.ListBoxFor in MVC),

I allow the user to select from the left selectbox and move the selected items to the right, this works great (see my example at: http://jsfiddle.net/tekguy/NJGzu/)

But how can I pass everything in the right listbox to MVC?

The problem occurs if the user accidently clicks on one item in the right box everything else gets un-selected and that will be the only value passed back to the controller.

Any ideas on how to remedy this? I was thinking about using javascript to select everything in the right textbox on form post. But are there any other ways to solve this issue?

HTML CODE:

```
<select id="list1" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value=">>" id="moveRight" />
<input type="button" value="<<" id="moveLeft" />

<select id="list2" multiple>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

JAVA-SCRIPT CODE:

```
$( function() {
    $('#moveRight').click(function(){
        $('#list1 option:selected').each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
        });
    });

    $('#moveLeft').click(function(){
        $('#list2 option:selected').each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar to this a while back for a project. I found only select items that were selected were posted back.
I used javascript as you suggested. Something like this worked for me.

```
$("#MassUpdateForm").submit(function() {
    $("#select_right").children("option").each(function() {
        this.selected = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop to append the elements.  A specific element can only exist once in the dom.. so unless you clone and append.. there's no need to remove the element first.  You can then change all the options to selected inside the submit event of the form

```
$(function () {
  $('#moveRight').click(function () {
    $('#list1 option:selected').appendTo("#list2"); // this will move all selected options to right side
  });
  $('#moveLeft').click(function () {
    $('#list2 option:selected').appendTo("#list1"); // this will move all selected options to left side
  });
  $('yourform').on('submit', function () {
    $('#list2 option').prop('selected', true); // set all options on right side to selected
  });
});
```